# Why can't I get properties count of navigator object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

Run in your browser (ES5+)

```
var propCount = Object.keys(navigator).length;
console.log(propCount); // 0
```

If you do it for a plain object like that

```
let obj = {
    foo: 'bar',
    breaking: 'bad'
}

let propCount = Object.keys(obj).length;

console.log(propCount); // 2
```

Why does it happen?

Sorry if it might relate to another problem like when `Object.keys(obj)` is only counting it for simple objects which do not contain `functions/arrays`, but this the 1st time I encountered with it.

And would like to know the reason of it.

Comment: They appear to be inherited properties, and `Object.keys()` only gives you "own" properties. `"appName" in navigator; // true` ... `navigator.hasOwnProperty("appName"); // false` Try using a simple `for-in` loop.

Comment: ...and I'd note that I'm not sure if the `navigator` object is spec'd to have enumerable properties. If not, then I'd be careful in relying on it in real-world code.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Object.keys() function returns properties of the object that are directly assigned to it. If you do the following:

```
console.log(navigator.hasOwnProperty('permissions')); // false
```

If you want to see properties of navigator do the following:

```
for(let i in navigator){
    console.log(i);
}
```

It will list all the properties of navigator object because for ... in ... loop includes object's prototype.

Comment: Careful, if `Object.prototype` is extended with an enumerable property, you will get unexpected properties. Same with an ES3 browser, but that's less of an issue.

Comment: The purpose of my post was to show that there is a difference between Object.keys() and for example for...in loop, that they work differently and Object.keys() looks only the the directly assigned properties. Someone can obviously extend Object.prototype and for...in loop will list that property as well but that was not my point.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: That's true of any added properties, not just on `Object.prototype`. The only way to safely get all properties excluding those specifically of `Object.prototype` would be to manually exclude it by starting with `navigator`, getting its properties using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames`, and then using `Object.getPrototypeOf` in a loop and doing the same until you reach `Object.prototype`, since there's no guarantee of how many levels of inheritance there will be. But that's overkill.

Comment: If some other code is extending `Object.prototype` without informing you, then it's just bad code. If some other code is doing that and you ignored its warnings in its API, then it's one's own fault. If you're doing it yourself, then you already know what to look for. So mostly a non-issue for competent developers.

Comment: @squint You shouldn't need to loop if [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator) is accurate, 2 levels will suffice. Some polyfills will also modify `Object.prototype` in an enumerable way.

Comment: @squint Many consider an unfiltered `for..in` bad practice, and both the popular [ESLint](http://eslint.org/docs/rules/guard-for-in) and [JSHint](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#forin) linters have rules to disallow them.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: Yes, linters have those rules, but they, like all rules, should be applied as appropriate for a given circumstance. If you have a codebase that allows such enumerable extensions, then a filter would be an important part of using `for-in`. If not, then there's no need for a filter. The only category left is being ignorant of such extensions to `Object.prototype`, and there's no excuse for that sort of ignorance *(which is the real bad practice)*.

Comment: @squint Unfortunately, you can never know the environment in which you code will execute, so it's not just a question of ignorance of your own codebase (which libraries like jQuery can never know), but of code quality and handling what is essentially undefined behavior. There is simply no guarantee that a user-agent will not include enumerable properties in the prototype chain, even if your codebase doesn't include them.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: Not sure what you mean by the user-agent including properties, but as a 3rd party developer like jQuery, you code your project with certain requirements that you publish. It's then the responsibility of the user of your library to make sure their environment works with the library. jQuery is a good example, since they do use unfiltered `for-in` loops.

Comment: @squint I mean the specification does not disallow unexpected enumerable properties (not that that would be 100% effective in practice even if it was), be it from the browser itself, some poorly written analytics script you didn't expect to change, or a browser extension. `for..in` loops basically add an unwritten, and difficult to test, dependency on undefined behavior to stay the way it was expected. And jQuery isn't the only such library, but the `for...in` loops I saw in my brief glance looked to be filtered.

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: jQuery has several unfiltered `for-in` loops, even in their `$.each` method. [Here's a quick demo](https://jsfiddle.net/bweey08q/) that illustrates it. In any case, writing a 3rd party library would be the exception, not the norm. It doesn't make sense to broadly require practices based on a tiny subset of situations. Any browser extension that puts enumerables on `Object.prototype` will be one that breaks so much real-world code that people will disable it immediately.

Answer (score 7):

That's because most properties of `navigator` are set on the `Navigator` prototype, which the `navigator` instance inherits, and [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) only returns the properties set on the `navigator` object itself.

You can get those properties from the prototype with this:

```
Object.keys(Object.getPrototypeOf(navigator));
```

On a side note, Firefox has the following properties in the `navigator` object itself:

```
[ "doNotTrack", "mozPay", "mozContacts", "mozApps" ]
```

Answer (score 1):

There are enumerable and non enumerable properties in javascript. [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) would return the enumerable own properties of an object. So in navigator object, it seems that there is no enumerable own properties. Hence `Object.keys(navigator)` is returning an empty array.

From the doc,

> The Object.keys() method returns an array of a given object's own
>   enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a
>   for...in loop.

If you want to list out all the enumerable and non enumerable properties of a certain object, then you have to write your own logic by using `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()`.

> Note : getOwnPropertyNames will return both enum/non enum own
>   properties of an object.

```
function getAllProps(obj, props = []){
 if(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj) == null){ return props; }
 return getAllProps(Object.getPrototypeOf(obj),
           props.concat(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj)));
}

console.log(getAllProps(navigator));
//This will give you all the properties.
```

If you use `for..in` loop then that will give you only the enumerable properties across the prototype chain. And you will have to miss the non enumerable properties.

Comment: @squint Yeah it is doing its job perfectly fine. for..in loop will iterate and collect the enumerable properties until it meets the null prototype.